# Formula en Excel diferencia de meses(fecha)

Tags: excel, formulas

Básicamente quiero hacer una fórmula por la cual yo tengo una columna de fechas y quiero que en otra me ponga un valor dependiendo si han pasado más de 1 mes ponga `>30` pero si ha pasado más de 2 ponga `>60` ; con respecto a la fecha actual.
He probado con estas lógicas pero no se ajusta al resultado que quiero. Gracias.

```
=SIFECHA(HOY(),E4,"d")

=SI(E4+31>HOY();">60",">30")

=SI(E4+60>HOY();">60";">30")
```

Comment: Lo quieres hacer en una columna del excel verdad? No quieres hacerlo en una macro.

Comment: A ver, quiero hacer una macro, pero me basta con saber hacer la formula porque la macro la tengo hecha, solo me falta que la fórmula se ajuste a lo que quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución para ponerlo todo en una línea seria haciendo funciones [anidadas](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/funci%C3%B3n-si-f%C3%B3rmulas-anidadas-y-c%C3%B3mo-evitar-problemas-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8).

Debemos empezar por la condición más restrictiva (la de mayor número) y ir poniendo condiciones inferiores.
Por lo que tu sentencia a usar quedaría como la siguiente.

```
=SI(HOY()>$A1+60;">60";SI(HOY()>$A1+31;">31";"VALOR SI NO SE CUMPLE NINGUNA CONDICION"))
```

*Cambia `$A1` por tus celdas.

PD: Ojo al problema si la fecha es hace 31 días exactos respecto hoy. No entrará en la condición. Podría considerarse añadir [MAYOR.O.IGUAL](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/mayor-o-igual-funci%C3%B3n-mayor-o-igual-f37e7d2a-41da-4129-be95-640883fca9df). Lo mismo si son 60 días.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Exacto, es lo que deseaba, lo que se me habia olvidado decir es que todas las posibilidades que hay son mayores de un mes, por que como mínimo será >30, y lo del mismo dia es solo esperar a que sea el dia siguiente, y volver a correr la macro, por lo que no hay problema. Muchas gracias.